# Why won't my icons load in a django environment(or what ever its called)?

Tags: html, django, font-awesome-5

Good evening everyone. I had been coding outside a virtual environment for quite some time, so i decided it was finally time to put my project on a django app/environment/server/whatever lol. However, my fontawesome icons did not load when i did so. I tried everything i could possibly do -- I tried using both internal and external links to fontawesome. My icons are still loading perfectly outside the virtual environment, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but issue with loading static files is most likely to be fix with the following command :

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Run the command on your terminal from the sevrer

Comment: I tried doing that, but when it asked me if i wanted to overwrite static, i  responded with yes and it produced an error message

Comment: Which error message ? Did you active your virtual env when running the command ?